# When a command is over half the terminal size it breaks

Tags: shell, command-line, terminal, prompt, putty

Whenever I type in a `bash` command longer than about half the width of the shell window I'm in, the command breaks like it would if I filled the whole screen

[image: image of problem]

- 3rd command in image - typed a few `x`s and got the expected result.
- 4th command - **typed a load more `x`s, and the command broke back to the start as though it had filled the whole line.**

**I'm connecting through Putty.**

I'm running Raspbian (a distro based on Debian)

*If I'm not being clear enough please say, it's not easy to explain.*

Comment: Is that putty your using?

Comment: Yes, should have said.

Comment: What is your `$PS1` variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that your tty is reporting the wrong tty size. Try running

```
pi@raspberrypi$ stty -aF /dev/ttyO0
```

There you will see how many rows and columns the tty thinks it has. This size should match the size set in putty. You can also change parameters, such as number of columns, using `stty`. The command would be something like

```
pi@raspberrypi$ stty -F /dev/ttyO0 cols 80
```

You can check more parameters at http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?stty

Comment: I am using PuTTY with all my Linux machines, like SCO and Ubuntu, and I just tried what you did @ACarter, and I didn't get any oddity. My PuTTY settings are default. So I am not sure if you might've changed something, or it could be an issue with how it is displaying for Raspbian.